# How to marshall cvMat and CV_MAT_ELEM

Tags: c#, opencv, pinvoke, marshalling

I'm trying to use some openCV Ml functions in c#, but i dont want to use the emugcv because my teachers wont let me, so i'm trying to marshall this two lines of code using p/invoke. 
(oh and should i use    the normal dll or the d.dll ?? )
and should i use calling conventions??

```
   CVAPI(CvMat*)  cvCreateMat( int rows, int cols, int type );//header def
    CvMat * rowtest = cvCreateMat(1,5,CV_32FC1);
```

for this one i have

```
[DllImportAttribute("opencv_ml242.dll.dll", EntryPoint="cvCreateMat")]
public static extern  IntPtr cvCreateMat(int dims, const ref int sizes, int type);

   #define CV_MAT_ELEM( mat, elemtype, row, col )           \
(*(elemtype*)CV_MAT_ELEM_PTR_FAST( mat, row, col, sizeof(elemtype)))

   #define CV_MAT_ELEM_PTR_FAST( mat, row, col, pix_size )  \
(assert( (unsigned)(row) < (unsigned)(mat).rows &&   \
         (unsigned)(col) < (unsigned)(mat).cols ),   \
 (mat).data.ptr + (size_t)(mat).step*(row) + (pix_size)*(col))
```

Im having trouble doing the this line (header above), can anyone help me pls? Thank you!

```
   CV_MAT_ELEM(*rowtest,float,0,0)
```

edit:
i found something for cv_mat_elem

```
   public static void CV_MAT_ELEM(ref Image<Gray, float> mat, Type elemtype, int row, int col, float val)
    {
        MCvMat cvMat = new MCvMat();
        cvMat.data = mat;

        CV_MAT_ELEM_PTR_FAST(ref cvMat, row, col, sizeof(float), val);

    public static void CV_MAT_ELEM_PTR_FAST(ref MCvMat mat, int row, int col, int pix_size, float val)
    {
        unsafe
        {
            int sz = sizeof(float);
            if (row < mat.rows)
            {
                if (col < mat.cols)
                {
                   IntPtr x = new IntPtr(&mat.data + sz * mat.step * row + sz * col);
                }
            }
        }        }
```

EDIT: solved using a DLL with my opencv functions, just hope i dont lose performance.

Answer (score 0):

solved using a DLL with my opencv functions, just hope i dont lose performance.